# dynamically find jquery element if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have a function, where if called, will update another object if it exists.  thing is, when the page is created the id is not known.

so, for example, heres my code:

```
$('.slides').on("slidestop", function() {
                    $this = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "action.php?event=ITEM "+$this.attr("data-itemID") + " " + this.value+"&itemID="+$this.attr("data-itemID"),
                        type:'POST',
                        success: function(result){
                            //update brightness slider if it exists
                            $("#sl" + $this.attr('data-itemID')).val(15);
                            $("#sl" + $this.attr('data-itemID')).slider("refresh");
                        },
                    });
                });
```

html:

```
 <input class='dimmerSlider' type='range' id='3' value='4' min='0' max='15' step='1' data-highlight='true' data-itemID='3'/>
```

error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

Comment: Use appropriate quotes, `$("#$this.attr("data-itemID")").val(15);` => `$("#$this.attr('data-itemID')").val(15);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#$this.attr('data-itemID')").val(15);
```

I am guessing you wanted to build a string using the attibute

```
$("#" + $this.attr('data-itemID')).val(15);
```

or use data instead of attr

```
$("#" + $this.data('itemID')).val(15);
```

---

To answer your second question if the element can not be found.

If you select an element with jQuery and it does not exist, it will be ignored when you run methods against it. If you need to know it does not exist than you can check the length

```
var x = $(".mySelector");
if (!x.length) {  //aka x.length===0
   console.log("not found");
}
```

Comment: i updated my original post with code...it seems to not be able to find the function...`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function`

Comment: Well is the slider plugin JavaScript included?

Comment: yeah...it seems to work if i hardcode it but not with the dynamic code....does this code pull the this.object or the string?  i only need the string value, not the object currently inside the function

Comment: *".it seems to work if i hardcode it"* Hard code what?

Answer (score 0):

> also, the element is not guaranteed to exist, how do i check for that
>   as well?

Try using [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) ,  [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```
  var elem = $("[id=" + $this.attr("data-itemID") + "]");
  if (elem.is("*")) {
    // do stuff
    elem.val(15)
    .slider("refresh");
  }
```